# Docker Virtual Hard Disk Location

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have installed docker on my windows 10 machine, I can see the location of the virtual hard disk in the 'Advance' option of settings, also I can change it when I use Linux containers.

But after switching on windows container 'Advance' option is not visible in settings, ***what is the location of stored images? when docker running with windows containers***